# Running new MVC3 solution in VS2010 ASP.NET development server; where is membership database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

*I'll preface this by saying: I don't really understand how membership providers work in ASP.NET, and I'm trying to understand them better.*

I just created a new MVC3 solution in VS2010. I can run it within ASP.NET's development server, and it works great - really cool. But what I'm a little confused about is just how forms authentication is working within the ASP.NET development server.

Consider the stock version of `AccountController.cs`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
            {
                return Redirect(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }
    }
```

It uses the `Membership` class to validate usernames and passwords that are registered through the MVC3 website. That's great, I get it, but... how exactly does this work? Especially within the ASP.NET development server?

Is there a database I can somehow open and look and see what test info I've entered? Where is it?

Like I said, I don't really understand how this works - and if I can't figure it out for the ASP.NET development server, then I certainly won't be able to figure it out in IIS. I've read through Microsoft's [Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) documentation, but I don't feel it really does a good job at explaining how this is working at a lower level; it seems to just say that membership is "built-in" - ok, that's cool, but there has to be more to the story than that, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you register a user checkout the `~/App_Data` folder of your application. That's where the database goes by default. Of course you might need a running SQLExpress instance.

Open your web.config and look at this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Then you could modify the connection string and use a real SQL Server database in your production environment instead of storing it locally in some files.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes sense. Just checked it out, that was exactly what I was looking for.